# How to model selenium page objects when there are common components across different pages?

Tags: java

This scenario can be observed commonly across different e-commerce applications where few components(links) are common(or displayed) in different pages. In this case, how do we model page objects in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I follow for this is to use inner classes respective to reusable Webelements.

Lets say Basket/Cart link will be available on all pages. So to reuse that on Product Detail page my approach will be :

```
public class ShoppingLocators {

  public static class CommonLocators {
    WebElement cart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a"));
   }
}

public class ProductDetail {

  public static class Locators extends ShoppingLocators.CommonLocators {
    // This inherits all methods and data members of CommonLocators inner class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **base class** [BasePage ] declare common component in this class.

And Extends this class in various other **child classes** where some other components are there. [PageA, PageB etc].

```
class BasePage {
//common components
}

class PageA extends BasePage {
//component of page A only
}


class PageB extends BasePage {
//component of page B only
}
```

Comment: Gaurav - Creating BaseClass as abstract class is considered as one of the best practices. But in this scenario I do not see it appropriate as if we create the BaseClass as abstract class and declare the common methods(components), then every sub class has to implement these methods even if a particular component is not required by that page. What do you think?

Comment: Why to use Abstract class? create a normal class and place all common components only[that anyways available on all pages so write implementation in base class only, no need to make it as abstract]